# Clean Messy Strings in DataFrame by a defined function in Python

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
AATest=pd.DataFrame({'IDNUM': ['1234\t','234', 'Spreedsheet ', '2345\t', '1257 ']})
AATest
```

I want to clean the dataset into below results:

```
AATest=pd.DataFrame({'IDNUM': ['1234', '2345', '1257']})
AATest
```

So I wrote a function, but it turned out it didn't work as I expected, could anyone help with any solution? Thanks so much~

```
    IDNUM
0   1234\t
2   Spreedsheet
3   2345\t
4   1257

def removedeb(data):
    if (data['IDNUM'].str.len()<4).any():
        data.drop(data[data['IDNUM'].str.len()<4].index, inplace=True)
    elif (data['IDNUM'].str.len()>4).any():
        data=data['IDNUM'].str.strip('\t').str.strip().to_frame()
    elif (data['IDNUM'].str.contains('Spreedsheet')).any():
        data.drop(data[data['IDNUM'].str.contains('Spreedsheet')].index, inplace=True)
    else: return data

removedeb(AATest)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this works for you :

```
a = {'IDNUM': ['1234\t','234', 'Spreedsheet ', '2345\t', '1257 ']}

for key, value in a.items():
    temp = []
    for i in value:
        try:
            if len(i.strip()) != len(i):
                temp.append(str(int(i.strip())))
        except ValueError:
            continue
    a[key] = temp

print(a)
```

output of this is : `{'IDNUM': ['1234', '2345', '1257']}`

Comment: Nice and simple solution, not requiring a bunch of `if` statements. Good job!

Comment: nice and clear logic, just needs a little edit to tailor to my result~ Thanks~

Comment: The problem is that 234 is not removed anyway, but that's a great logic though

Comment: Hey @ShangLu, I have updated my answer, can you please check and let me know whether this works for you or not?

Comment: Thanks Sankar, I was trying to do the same thing before you updated, but your code still seems cooler than my "tried" version lol~ Super thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `else` or `elif`: three `if`'s should be fine.